# Install target in namespace

Tags: c++, cmake

How do I install a target in a namespace with cmake?

I have the following setup and want to export foo::core and foo::bar for use in other projects:

```
project(foo)

add_library(core)
add_library(foo::core ALIAS core)

add_library(bar)
add_library(foo::bar ALIAS core)

install(TARGETS core bar EXPORT fooConfig)
install(EXPORT fooConfig NAMESPACE foo)
export(TARGETS core bar FILES fooConfig.cmake)
```

I can use find_package to find my foo libaray and can link against my core and bar libraries, but they do not reside in the foo namespace

```
project(different_project)
find_package(foo REQUIRED)

add_executable(example)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE core bar) # this is possible
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE foo::core foo::bar) # this is what i want, but not possible
```

Comment: `install(TARGETS core bar foo::core foo::bar ...)` ? The `::` are just not special in cmake. You could use `_`.

Comment: @KamilCuk install(TARGETS ... foo::core ...) is causing a CMake error because you can not install alias targets.

Comment: `NAMESPACE` option exists **both** for `install(EXPORT)` and `export()` commands. You don't use this option in the latter case, this is why your imported targets are not namespaced. While you don't specify that in the question post, your  `find_package(foo)` most likely finds the config file in the **build tree** (produced by `export()`), not in the install tree (produced by `install(EXPORT)` with following *installation* of the project).

Comment: @Tsyvarev this solved the problem for me. You can consider making it to an answer, so i can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `NAMESPACE` is supported for both `install(EXPORT)` and `export()` commands.

So, for add namespace in the **install tree** use

```
install(TARGETS core bar EXPORT fooConfig)
install(EXPORT fooConfig NAMESPACE foo)
```

and for the same in the **build tree** use

```
export(TARGETS core bar NAMESPACE foo FILE fooConfig.cmake)
```